# Apex Code for Record Creation and Modification

Tags: cloud, salesforce, apex-code

I am new to writing code in APEX for salesforce.com. I have an Object 'UnProc' with 10 fields and it is 'POPULATED'. I have two more objects ('Account and Contact') with 5 fields each and these Objects have to be populated. I have to write an APEX code using the batch apex and scheduler so that i can create new records for 'Account' and 'Contact' takin the records which are already there in the 'UnProc'. After the Account and Contact fields get populated with the UnProc records. The UnProc record has to be deleted.

I have already read the batch apex and scheduler related docs on saleforce.com and have understood and created the class structure for them. Where i am stuck at is the record retrievel, creation stuff etc. Database is my weakness thats why i cannot get through it. Pseoudo code or some lines of code can be useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally records are retrieved from the database in Apex code using SOQL. The basic syntax is outlined [here](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_select.htm).

Records are retrieved from the database and sent back to the database as sObjects, which are essentially a collection of fields. a SOQL query will generally return a list of sObjects, like so:

```
list<UnProc__c> unProcs = [select accountField1__c, accountField2__c, ... contactField1__c, contactField2__c, ... contactField5__c from UnProc__c];
```

Once you have retrieved these records, you can create new Account and Contact records by simply creating lists of Account and Contact sObjects, populating their fields from the UnProc object and then commit them to the database like so:

```
list<Account> accs = new list<Account>();
list<Contact> cons = new list<Contact>();
Account acc;
Contact con;
for(UnProc__c up : unProcs) {
    acc = new Account();
    con = new Contact();
    acc.field1 = up.accountField1;
    acc.field2 = up.accountField2;
    ...
    con.field1 = up.contactField1;
    con.field2 = up.contactField2;
    ...
    con.field5 = up.contactField5;
    accs.add(acc);
    cons.add(con);
}
database.insert(accs);
database.insert(cons);
```

In Apex you should retrieve and commit to the database in collections of records, rather than individually, since there are limits to how many queries and commits you can run in a single execution context.